# Can JLable's name combine with int data?

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jlabel

i know that 
first code is correct, and the second code is not correct.
if i want to insert i into JLabel. how can it be achieve?

```
JLabel label_1 = new JLabel();
int i = 1; JLabel label_i = new JLabel();
```

Comment: this cannot be achevied.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in Java. You could use arrays:

```
JLabel[] array = new JLabel[2];
array[0] = new JLabel();
array[1] = new JLabel();
```

or *Collections*, for example an `ArrayList`:

```
List<JLabel> arrayList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
arrayList.add(new JLabel());
// ...
arrayList.get(0).setText("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 1;    
JLabel label_i = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question refers to "dynamic variable names" where variable names can be specified by using *other variables* such as :

```
String x1 = "stuff";

int w = 2;

String x"w" = "stuff 2";
```

where `"w"` refers to the variable value of w (2) then that cannot be done directly in java.

However, arrays and collections can be used instead of this:

```
//JLabel Array of 5 elements
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[5];

int index = 3;

labels[index] = ... //Accesses and assigns index 3
```

Similarly, this can be done with an ArrayList if you want an growable array:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>(); //New empty arraylist of JLabels

//Populate arraylist
labels.add(new JLabel());

int index = 0;

JLabel label = labels.get(index);

label.setText(...);
```

If you live on the bleeding-edge, you may want to consider reading [this](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118) which shows Java 8's somewhat limited (but still possible) ability to get individual variable names via reflection.